# How to efficiently select a range in an observable collection into another observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, range, observablecollection

Something like (pseudo code)

```
ObservableCollection<TheClass> ob1 = new ObservableCollection<TheClass>();
ob1.Add(...);
ob1.Add(...); 
ob1.Add(...);
ob1.Add(...); 
ObservableCollection<TheClass> ob2;
ob2 = ob1.Range(0, 2);
```

Keeping into account that both collections can contains a large amount of data.

thanks

Comment: How about using this [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc679169.aspx): `ob2 = new ObservableCollection<TheClass>(ob1.Take(2));`? Btw. the "amount" of data should not be much of a problem, because you're only copying references, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ObservableCollection` doesn't support `AddRange` method. You can extend the functionality of the `ObservableCollection` class by writing an **extension method** or by creating a new class that derives from the `ObservableCollection` class. For example:

```
public class ObservableRangeCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        var enumerable = collection as T[] ?? collection.ToArray();
        foreach (var item in enumerable)
        {
            Items.Add(item);
        }
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, enumerable.ToList()));
    }
}
```

Then you can create an instance of `ObservableRangeCollection` instead of `ObservableCollection` for `ob2` and use `AddRange` and get your favorite range by using `Skip` and `Take` like this:

```
ObservableRangeCollection<TheClass> ob2 = new ObservableRangeCollection<TheClass>();
ob2.AddRange(ob1.Take(3));//Returns 3 number of contiguous elements from the start 
// Or to  grab a Range between 2 and 5
ob2.AddRange(ob1.Skip(2).Take(3))
```

Comment: @user2946329 your answer is correct, I posted the same answer myself before seeing you already provided it and deleted my own. How is this even being discussed?

Comment: @MarkFeldman which answer are you referring to? I no longer see it. If you don't mind reposting I would appreciate it.

Comment: @user2481095 As he clearly said he deleted it and it is no longer available. What about this accepted answer ??

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me. If I try to add multiple items at once I get a  "Range actions are not supported" exception. It seems the only way to get around this is to pass a NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset instead. However I want to be notified of the new items that were added. I have not found a way to accomplish this.

Comment: @user2481095 It is unclear for someone to guess what are you trying. It would be better to ask a new question and reference to this question and show your code and say what exactly doesn't work for you.

Comment: @S.Akbari Your solution doesn't work for me when attempting to use the AddRange function to add a list of multiple objects. I get a "Range actions are not supported" exception. You won't get this exception if you add a single object, but the point of an AddRange function is having the ability to add multiple items at a time. Notifying with Reset gets around this, However I want to be notified of the new items that were added. I have not found a way to accomplish this. I think this is the limitation of trying to inherit from ObservableCollection. I don't think the class was designed for this.

Comment: @user2481095 The OP asked for multiple object based on his question and this answer has worked for he since he accepted it. If it doesn't work for you probably you have missing something over here and as I already suggested it would be better to ask a new question and also referencing to this question in your new question.

Answer (score 5):

```
ObservableCollection<TheClass> ob1 = new ObservableCollection<TheClass>();
ob1.Add(...);
ob1.Add(...); 
ob1.Add(...);
ob1.Add(...); 
ObservableCollection<TheClass> ob2;

// ob2 = ob1.Range(0, 2);
ob2 = new ObservableCollection(ob1.Skip(0).Take(2));
```

Now if you *really* insist on that `.Range` method, you could write an extension yourself:

```
public static class ObservableCollectionExtensions
{
    public static ObservableCollection<T> Range(this ObservableCollection<T> sequence, int start, int count)
    {
         return new ObservableCollection(sequence.Skip(start).Take(count));
    }
}
```

Now your code should compile:

```
ObservableCollection<TheClass> ob1 = new ObservableCollection<TheClass>();
ob1.Add(...);
ob1.Add(...); 
ob1.Add(...);
ob1.Add(...); 
ObservableCollection<TheClass> ob2;

ob2 = ob1.Range(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this, where ever you keep your extension methods.

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> Range<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> oc, uint startIndex, uint length) => 
    oc.Skip(startIndex).Take(length);
```

And use it like this:

```
ob2 = ob1.Range(0, 2);
```